# Why fgets() works wrong?

Tags: c, eclipse, fgets

Here's my code

```
if(passwordCorretta(ds_sock)){
   printf("CLIENT: password aggiungi corretta\n");

   do{
      printf("Cognome >> ");
      fgets(cognome,sizeof(cognome),stdin);
      //scanf("%s", cognome);
      printf("Nome >> ");
      fgets(nome,sizeof(nome),stdin);
      //scanf("%s", nome);
      printf("Telefono >> ");
      fgets(telefono,sizeof(telefono),stdin);
      //scanf("%s", telefono);
```

in output print first the two printf,skipping first fgets(), why is that?

here's my output

```
CLIENT: password aggiungi corretta
Cognome >> Nome >> **my input
Telefono >> **my input
```

any ideas why? thanks

Here's my entire function

```
void main(){
int ds_sock, length, res;
struct sockaddr_in client;
struct hostent *hp;
char oper[2];

int risPwd;
int op;

char cognome[30];
char nome[20];
char telefono[12];

char continua[3];
char ris[2];
int trovato;
int aggiunto;

ds_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = 1999;

hp = gethostbyname("localhost");  //indirizzo del server
memcpy(&client.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, 4);

res = connect(ds_sock, &client, sizeof(client));
if(res==-1) {
    perror("Errore nella connessione");
}

signal(SIGPIPE, gest_broken_pipe);
signal(SIGINT, gest_interruzione);

do{
    op=scelta();
    sprintf(oper,"%d",op);
    if(write(ds_sock, oper, sizeof(oper))<0){
        if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
    }

    switch(op){
            case 1:
                printf("INSERIMENTO NUOVO CONTATTO\n");

                if(passwordCorretta(ds_sock)){
                    printf("CLIENT: password aggiungi corretta\n");

                    do{
                        printf("Cognome >> ");
                        fgets(cognome,sizeof(cognome),stdin);
                        //scanf("%s", cognome);
                        printf("Nome >> ");
                        fgets(nome,sizeof(nome),stdin);
                        //scanf("%s", nome);
                        printf("Telefono >> ");
                        fgets(telefono,sizeof(telefono),stdin);
                        //scanf("%s", telefono);
                        if(write(ds_sock, cognome, sizeof(cognome))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }
                        if(write(ds_sock, nome, sizeof(nome))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }
                        if(write(ds_sock, telefono, sizeof(telefono))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }

                        if(read(ds_sock, ris, sizeof(ris))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di lettura");
                        }
                        trovato=atoi(ris);

                        switch(trovato){
                            case 0:
                                printf("Errore di lettura nel Server\n");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                printf("Il contatto è già presente nell'elenco\n");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                if(read(ds_sock, ris, sizeof(ris))<0){
                                    if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di lettura");
                                }
                                aggiunto=atoi(ris);
                                if(aggiunto==0) printf("Errore di scrittura nel Server\n");
                                else printf("Il contatto è stato correttamente inserito nell'elenco\n");
                                break;
                        }

                        printf("Vuoi aggiungere un altro contatto? [SI/NO]\n");
                        scanf("%s", continua);
                        if(write(ds_sock, continua, sizeof(continua))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }
                    }while(strcmp(continua, "SI")==0);

                }
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("RICERCA DI UN NUMERO TELEFONICO\n");

                if(passwordCorretta(ds_sock)){
                    printf("CLIENT: password cerca corretta\n");

                    do{
                        printf("Cognome >> ");
                        scanf("%s", cognome);
                        printf("Nome >> ");
                        scanf("%s", nome);
                        if(write(ds_sock, cognome, sizeof(cognome))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }
                        if(write(ds_sock, nome, sizeof(nome))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }

                        if(read(ds_sock, ris, sizeof(ris))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di lettura");
                        }
                        trovato=atoi(ris);

                        switch(trovato){
                            case 0:
                                printf("Errore di lettura nel Server\n");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                if(read(ds_sock, telefono, sizeof(telefono))<0){
                                    if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di lettura");
                                }
                                if(strcmp(telefono, "errore")==0) printf("Errore di lettura nel Server\n");
                                else printf("Il telefono del contatto richiesto è: %s\n", telefono);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                printf("Il contatto non è presente nell'elenco\n");
                                break;
                        }

                        printf("Vuoi cercare un altro numero di telefono? [SI/NO]\n");
                        scanf("%s", continua);
                        if(write(ds_sock, continua, sizeof(continua))<0){
                            if(errno!=EINTR) perror("Errore di scrittura");
                        }
                    }while(strcmp(continua, "SI")==0);

                }
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("USCITA\n");
                break;

            case 0:
                printf("Eseguito lo SHUTDOWN del Server\n");
                break;
    }

}while(op!=3 && op!=0);

close(ds_sock);
```

}

i use 3 buffer named cognome,nome,telefono. ideas?

Comment: I think that you skipped the important part of the code.

Comment: Show the definitions of `cognome`, `gnome`, and `telefono`.

Comment: i do that on purpose because there are many lines of code, but if is usefull i can post all code

Comment: It's probably consuming a line already present in the input buffer. My guess would be that you are using `scanf()` (or `getchar()`) before using `fgets()`.

Comment: @Greg917 What's in `scelta()`? And specifically, does it read stdin?

Comment: If you know that there is something left in input buffer, just add a `fgets` before `printf("Cognome >> ");` - no, joking - it could work but is ugly until you know **why**

Comment: 'int scelta(){
 int comando;
 menu();
 puts("Inserisci l'operazione da effettuare: ");
 fgets(comando,sizeof(comando),stdin);
 //scanf("%d", &comando);
 while(comando<0 || comando>3){
  puts("Operazione sconosciuta, riprovare: ");
  menu();
  fgets(comando,sizeof(comando),stdin);
  //scanf("%d", &comando);
 }
 return comando;
}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is supported by your system, the function `fpurge` cleans input streams and could be used in that case :

```
if(passwordCorretta(ds_sock)){
   fpurge(stdin);
   printf("CLIENT: password aggiungi corretta\n");

   do{
```

and do not try to use `fflush` because it only acts on output streams.

But anyway, you should try to understand where the unwanted input comes from. This is not far from a quick and dirty hack but at least is harmless is nothing was left in buffer.

Comment: using fpurge(stdin) i solved the wrong output,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `scelta()` function. Both versions of it (with `scanf()` or `fgets()`) are wrong.

First I will explain why your `fgets()` version is wrong.

You declared `comando` as `int`, while `fgets()` expects a `char *`. This is undefined behavior, and you're lucky (or unlucky) it didn't crash.

As for your `scanf()` version: This is exactly what I predicted in the comments. `scanf()` only reads the integer input, and leaves the new line (ENTER key) in the input buffer. This means that your first `fgets()` call in `main()` is reading this left-over ENTER key.

One way of doing this correctly is as follows:

```
long int scelta() {
    char input[20];
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin); // this reads input
    while(strchr(input, '\n') == NULL) {
        // the input has not ended
        // it is probably not a long int anyway but you still need to consume it
        // choose your appropriate action, e.g.
        while(getchar() != '\n'); // read everything in input buffer up to (and including) the ENTER key
        puts("error");
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin); // read input again
    }
    char *endptr;
    long int comando = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);
    // then check range and check for errors with endptr
    return comando;
}
```

For a detailed description and example code (with error-checking) of `strtol()`, please refer to the [*Linux Programmer's Manual*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Comment: thanks for advices, i immediately work to improve and correct my code